# Wordpress on AWS with ELB

Tags: plugins, php, multisite, wp-admin

The plan is to install wordpress on AWS with ELB. So far I have two instances of Ubuntu 16.04 each with PHP7 and both connected to RDS (MariaDB).

The PHP Session is shared between the ec2 instances and hosted in ElastiCache (Memcached). So in php.ini, at the session section, I use memcached. If I have only one ec2 under the ELB, I can login to the admin and all is perfect.

The problem is when have both of them under ELB (the exact same config) the website is working but the login in the admin no any more. Does someone have any idea/clue/suggestion about this matter? Thank you

Comment: Are still using this setup or moved to the elastic cache??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve this issue. The problem i had was on the ELB with the sticky sessions. I just enabled it and set a time of 3600 and now wordpress in login in users. A question remains with the real ELB power. If you do this sticky session I found some documentation that says the user is bind to one single EC2 exclusively .. feel free to comment over this. Thanks again

Comment: Can you mark this as the accepted answer?